# Hard drive appears to be corrupted after a botched partition move/expand

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I moved `/` and `/boot` onto an M.2 drive, leaving `/home` on my SSD. After ensuring M.2 drive was booting correctly I started a LiveCD (Pop_OS because it's what I had around and it's Ubuntu more or less) and used gparted to delete the partitions on the SSD and then expand `/home` to the entire size of the SSD.

Apparently when Pop_OS' LiveCD is inactive it doesn't sleep or turn the screen off, it logs you out. And it logged me out midway through this above process.

"Grr!" but that's ok because I am not too attached to the contents of `/home` it was rsync'd to my laptop yesterday. So I load up Arch and it panics because systemd cannot find `/home` by UUID. No biggie, UUID must have changed. `lsblk` no longer shows my SSD. Weird.

End up back on the LiveCD. Gparted does show my SSD from the LiveCD. But it's throwing I/O errors. I try to use `parted` to access it, same I/O errors. I attempt to use `gsmartcontrol`, it shows the drive but no data about that drive (at least gparted showed the drive size).

I drop back to BIOS and pull up the SMART disk utility, except it doesn't see my drive either.

Any chance this thing can be recovered? I don't care about the data at all, I care about being out a $300 SSD that wasn't even four months old.

Comment: A 4 month old SSD will be under warranty. So no loss.

Answer (score 0):

After a good night's rest and some coffee I came back to this problem and was able to solve it.

First, I went into BIOS and turned SATA port 3, where this drive is connected to, off, rebooted, went back into BIOS turned SATA port 3 back on, rebooted, and now my Arch install sees the drive as does my BIOS. So far so good.

I ran `cgdisk` and `sfdisk` and I can see `sdb5` but I cannot access it, mount it, or get any data about it. Looking at `cgdisk` it appears that the partition table, both main and backup, are totally borked. OK, so no easy data retrieval --again I just want a not-dead drive.

Decide to see if I can forcefully wipe the drive clean so...

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4096 count=1`

That wipes the drive, writing zeros to the entire disk.

Next step:

`sgdisk -o /dev/sdb`

Which returned an error and asked me to run with the `-e` flag. Did that and it successfully restored the main partition table.

Spun up gparted, deleted the partition table, created a new table, created a new partition, and viola! `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/` finally succeeded.

Used rsync to copy my laptop's `/home` to my newly restored SSD on my desktop and I am back up and running!